# File not deleting TCL

Tags: tcl, scheduled-tasks, network-drive

Something is lying...

Keep in mind that this works as expected when I run the script manually, but not when it is run via task scheduler.

I have a TCL script that is supposed to check to see if a file exists on a network drive and delete it if it does. I do this by:

```
if {[file exists X:/path/to/file.txt]} {
    log_output "Deleting file X:/path/to/file.txt"
    file delete -force X:/path/to/file.txt
}
```

and i noticed that the file was never being deleted when run via Task Scheduler. So I preformed another check to try to get more information.

```
if {[file exists X:/path/to/file.txt]} {
    log_output "File X:/path/to/file.txt NOT DELETED!"
} else {
    log_output "File X:/path/to/file.txt DELETED!"
}
```

My output is:

```
Deleting file X:/path/to/file.txt
File X:/path/to/file.txt DELETED!
```

The second line confirms that the file was actually reported as deleted as the exists check failed. Finally, I then run a command that generates a new file.

```
exec myProgram --outFile X:/path/to/file.txt
```

Again, the weird thing is when I run this script manually, it works just fine. However, When I have it set to run via task scheduler (using Win7), the old file is not deleted even though the output log shows it was:

```
Deleting file X:/path/to/file.txt
File X:/path/to/file.txt DELETED!
```

When I check the date and time stamp of the file it is always from the last time I preformed a manual run. I thought it was more of a permissions error, but this doesnt make sense. Why would it report as deleted and still be there unchanged?

To be thorough, I tried some other workarounds. Instead of writing a file to the network drive via the command, I tried writing it locally:

```
if {[file exists C:/path/to/file.txt]} {
    log_output "Deleting file C:/path/to/file.txt"
    file delete -force C:/path/to/file.txt
}
if {[file exists C:/path/to/file.txt]} {
    log_output "File C:/path/to/file.txt NOT DELETED!"
} else {
    log_output "File C:/path/to/file.txt DELETED!"
}

exec myProgram --outFile C:/path/to/file.txt
```

Then copying it to the network drive:

```
file copy -force C:/path/to/file.txt X:/path/to/file.txt
file copy -force C:/path/to/file.txt X:/path/to/file1.txt
```

I get:

```
Deleting file X:/path/to/file.txt
File X:/path/to/file.txt DELETED!
Deleting file C:/path/to/file.txt
File C:/path/to/file.txt DELETED!
```

But sure enough, the old file remains and the new file 'file1.txt' does not exist...

Again, manual runs always result in success.

Comment: File mapping in scheduled-tasks is hard. use the UNC path. (`//machine/share/path/to/file.txt`)

Comment: Yes, I also tried that. Same results. Works as expected for manual runs. Fails when run by Task Scheduler even though the output log shows the files as deleted.

Comment: Does the scheduled task have permission to delete the file?

Comment: Yes. It has full permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1.Set the file location or path in a variable as

```
set way "/XX/XXX".
```

2.Apply this

```
if {[file exists $way/file.txt]} {
    exec rm -f $way/file.txt 
}
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: "I hope this will work" is not very convincing. I hope it works too, and if it does the questioner will, I hope, respond that it does, and you'll clean this up. Perhaps in the meanwhile you could explain why you think this will work?